# Problema etiquetas mat HTML en Angular 8.2.14

Tags: nodejs, angular, typescript

Cuando compilo mi módulo Angular, me salta este error de parseo HTML:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'mat-card-title' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-card-title' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card-title' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    [ERROR ->]<mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
"): ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.html@11:4
'mat-card-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-card-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card-header' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. (
```

Estos son los ficheros que he modificado hasta ahora:

**material.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {
  MatCardModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatMenuModule,
   MatButtonModule,
   MatToolbarModule,
   MatIconModule,
   MatBadgeModule,
   MatSidenavModule,
   MatListModule,
   MatGridListModule,
   MatFormFieldModule,
   MatInputModule,
   MatSelectModule,
   MatRadioModule,
   MatDatepickerModule,
   MatNativeDateModule,
   MatChipsModule,
   MatTooltipModule,
   MatTableModule,
   MatPaginatorModule,
   MatProgressSpinnerModule
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
   imports: [
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      CommonModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatSidenavModule,
      MatBadgeModule,
      MatListModule,
      MatGridListModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatRadioModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatNativeDateModule,
      MatChipsModule,
      MatTooltipModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatPaginatorModule
   ],
   exports: [
    MatCardModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatToolbarModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatSidenavModule,
      MatBadgeModule,
      MatListModule,
      MatGridListModule,
      MatInputModule,
      MatFormFieldModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatRadioModule,
      MatDatepickerModule,
      MatChipsModule,
      MatTooltipModule,
      MatTableModule,
      MatPaginatorModule
   ],
   providers: [
      MatDatepickerModule,
   ]
})

export class MaterialModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import {BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService} from './service/basic-auth-interceptor.service';
import {MatCardModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatProgressSpinnerModule, MatTableModule, MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    UserComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatTableModule
  ],
  providers: [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService, multi: true }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "conexiona-angular-client-web-dos",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "bufferutil": "^4.0.1",
    "chokidar": "^3.4.2",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "utf-8-validate": "^5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.29",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^5.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

**styles.css**

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons';
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

**login.component.html**

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Login</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
    <form>
      <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <input matInput placeholder="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" name="username" required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
              <input matInput placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" name="password" required>
            </mat-form-field>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <p *ngIf="error" class="error">
          {{ error }}
        </p>
      </table>
    </form>
    <mat-spinner [style.display]="showSpinner ? 'block' : 'none'"></mat-spinner>
  </mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="checkLogin()" color="primary">Login</button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Algunas preguntas relacionadas con ello: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479557/how-do-you-deal-with-div-with-mat-card-header-text-in-an-material2-card/47439591, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56705672/how-can-i-align-a-material-icon-header-text-on-the-same-line?rq=1

Cómo tengo que hacer en esta versión para que se pueda visualizar el login, junto con el CSS? Muchas gracias por la ayuda :)

Comment: La clase `MaterialModule` no está en la lista de imports de tu `AppModule`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente, el problema estaba en que no reconocía MaterialModule en la AppModule

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './footer/footer.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService } from './service/basic-auth-interceptor.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    UserComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    LogoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: BasicAuthHtppInterceptorService, multi: true }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Y en MaterialModule hay que ir especificando las rutas de cada componente asociado a sus etiquetas HTML:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { A11yModule } from '@angular/cdk/a11y';
import { DragDropModule } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';
import { PortalModule } from '@angular/cdk/portal';
import { ScrollingModule } from '@angular/cdk/scrolling';
import { CdkStepperModule } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { CdkTableModule } from '@angular/cdk/table';
import { CdkTreeModule } from '@angular/cdk/tree';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatBottomSheetModule } from '@angular/material/bottom-sheet';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatNativeDateModule, MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    A11yModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule
  ],
  imports: [
    A11yModule,
    CdkStepperModule,
    CdkTableModule,
    CdkTreeModule,
    DragDropModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatBottomSheetModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    PortalModule,
    ScrollingModule
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

@PabloLozano muchas gracias, como siempre. :)